# Is it possible to execute a bigquery stored procedure via the REST API?

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to programatically execute a bigquery stored procedure via the REST API. I've experimented with the https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/insert method  using the interactive API explorer on that page, but no luck so far. I've tried the following as the request body:

```
{
  "configuration": {
    "query": {
      "query": "call mydataset.mystoredprocedure"
    }
  }
}
```

and

```
{
  "configuration": {
    "query": {
      "query": "mydataset.mystoredprocedure"
    }
  }
}
```

and

```
{
  "configuration": {
    "query": {
      "query": "call mydataset.mystoredprocedure()"
    }
  }
}
```

and

```
{
  "configuration": {
    "query": {
      "query": "mydataset.mystoredprocedure()"
    }
  }
}
```

but all of those fail with error **invalidQuery**.

Is there a way to execute a stored procedure using the REST API?

The reason for my asking is because I would like to trigger the execution of my stored procedure from Google Cloud Scheduler and I can't figure out a way of doing that other than calling the API.

Comment: Hi @jamiet, please which will be the correct way to call a stored procedure with parameters? Can't really find an example in the docs. Using Java but I don't think it matters. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're likely getting the issue because the default at the REST level is to use the legacy SQL syntax when evaluating the query.  Try adding `"useLegacySql": false` to the query config section.

More info here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job#JobConfigurationQuery